# desire2learn valence.desire2learn.com test user accounts

Tags: desire2learn

If I wanted to kick the tires with developing for the desire2learn platform, but don't have a desire2learn installation to develop against, can I use the valence.desire2learn.com environment.  How can I get a user login for that environment?  Do I get one when I request an app developer key?

Comment: This question appears to be primarily about gaining access to a specific product.  While not necessarily off-topic for this site, after looking through the pages of desire2learn.com for a few minutes I found answers to two of your questions, so I would suggest doing some research and then making your questions more specific.

Comment: How much more specific can I make my question?  How about this?  I want to know if it's possible to access their valence.desire2learn.com environment and play with their APIs without enrolling in their partner program which looks much more heavyweight.  I've spent about 90 mins going through their documentation and I don't see the answers to any of my questions...if you could point me at the approriate pages on their site I'd be very grateful...

Comment: That does indeed clarify what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps you can take as a Valence API user to get yourself working:

1. Download a [client library](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/clients/index.html) and work with it, and the [getting started sample](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/samples/gettingStarted.html), to get up and running against 'valence.desire2learn.com'. The sample has a set of test App credentials, and a test user that you can use to make one or two simple calls: get the product version table from the test LMS, and get the 'whoami' information for the test user.

   You can use this level of bootstrapping to get your self up to the stage where you have a client framework that can go through the authentication process with an LMS, and then create authenticated URls to make API calls against an LMS.
2. The next step for real work requires you to have an LMS against which you can work, and a user account on that LMS. There are several scenarios you can try here:

   - Work with an existing vendor or institution that does have a test environment you can test against.
   - Go through the steps required to become a [D2L Partner](http://www.desire2learn.com/partners/): once you do that, the partnership program can provide you with a test LMS you can use for your development needs.

Answer (score 1):

The process of using the desire2learn key tool is documented [here](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/clients/tools/keytool.html) and only requires that you have a google account to login to the tool.  Their key tool allows you to "choose to create a non-commercial key for an application during trial and development phases of its life" and "from this page you can only immediate accept the Non-Commercial Developer Agreement with D2L; if you seek to accept a Commercial Developer agreement with D2L, we handle that request through the Partner Network."  Thus, the key tool allows you to get an app developer key without enrolling in their partner program.

You may also want to check out the getting started with Valence [page](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/firstlist.html).

Comment: thanks, I'd already checked out all those pages and applied for an app developer key (still pending), but still not clear if that will give me an end-user login to their api environment.

The readme that comes with one of their getting started samples states:

3) Click on the 'Authenticate' button
 - You should be redirected to the Desire2Learn login page
   hosted on https://valence.desire2learn.com.
 - Fill out your username and password.

... but it doesn't say where to get a username/password...